# When to use ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream?

Tags: android, inputstream

Under what circumstances should I make a **ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream** instead of an ordinary **InputStream** in Android?

I don't understand the difference.

Comment: when you are passing a `ParcelFileDescriptor` to some other process

Comment: I am doing that using: InputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()); Why is that not good?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.java#838 ;-)

Comment: OK, so the ParcelFileDescriptor actually also has to be closed, which is otherwise easily forgotten. Right?

Comment: it seems so, besides it is just easier to call new ACIS with PFD as a param than calling getFileDescriptor()